# Regular Expression for Decimal and 10^-3

Tags: regex, google-forms

I need a regular expression for all these forms

```
52.356*10^-5
52.356*10^5
56*10^-5
56*10^5 
5.566
0.3650
```

I need all these forms in one regular expression if possible, because I'm making a quiz for my students and they can enter a decimal number in the form or a decimal number times 10 power any -ve or +ve number

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In your case, check out https://regex101.com/ which is really quite powerful! Also consider if you need a regex or if you can verify the values some other way.

Comment: Do you want to match only exatly these numbers, or are these examples of patterns you'd like to cover?

Answer (score 0):

Try - `^-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\*10\^-?\d+)?$`

Check out the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/MyyxVN/2)

### Explanation

- `-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - Matches a decimal number (positive or negative) - allowing both fractionals and whole numbers (`542` and `5.42` are both valid)

  - `-?` - Optional negative sign
  - `\d+` - One or more digits
  - `(?:\.\d+)?` - Optional fractional part (inside a non capturing group)
- `(?:\*10\^-?\d+)?` - **Optionally** matches the exponent part - a multiplication sign (`*`) followed by the number `10`, followed by the exponentiation sign (`^`), followed by an optional negative sign, followed by a whole number

  - `\*` - The `*` sign - literally
  - `10` - The number 10 - literally
  - `\^` - The `^` sign - literally
  - `-?` - Optional negative sign
  - `\d+` - Whole number

Note the anchors `^` and `$` on both sides of the regex. The regex is tested on a full line.